# How to get information of a deleted video through YouTube api v2/v3 (JSON)

Tags: json, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm currently working on a project that tracks videos to be deleted.
And I'm saving only the `videoId`and `channelId` from the video information and the rest is still a request from youtube.

Is there a way can I get at least the video name or channel from the deleted videos.

I'm currently using YouTube api Version 3.

Edit:

I tried to use this feed with this deleted video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-KUqyqPRog

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/d-KUqyqPRog/responses?alt=json&prettyprint=true

Answer (score 2):

Once a video is deleted it is [removed](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_updating_and_deleting_videos#Deleting_a_video) by YouTube so you cannot lookup any of its previous details.

Comment: Using V3 - I have a video, for example with video-Id 'wspfM3QL874', which I -can- lookup information about, but it has been removed due to copyright claim.